# Silverlight 5 - odd visible border around button label or image?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

anyone have a thought why I get these rectangular borders inside buttons like this? thanks!

[image] [image]

Comment: If this is not a typical problem, it will be hard to find a solution without any source.

Comment: Any source would immediately put you to sleep, the above being the result of class upon class of inheritance. So rather than hoping for a solution, I only hope for a few 'yeah I've seen that' or 'you might want to check blah blah' to put me on a path.

Comment: If you can see them in blend, I'd dig into the control template hierarchy to find the unwanted parts. Otherwise there are tools like xamlspy that let you investigate the visual tree at run time. Since the element names are preserved at run time, this can help you to figure out where the problem is.